# php pregmatch all elements to array

Tags: php, url, preg-match-all

```
<a href="/position/memory1"> kw random</a>
<a href="/position/memory2"> kw2 random2</a>
<a href="/position/memory3"> 123 orange</a>
<a href="/position/memory4"> test apple</a>
<a href="/position/memory5"> bla</a>
<div>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword1"> kw random</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword2"> kw2 random2</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword3" rel="nofollow"> 123 orange</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword4"> test apple</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword5" title="something"> bla</a>
</div>
```

how to extract `keyword1`, `keyword2`, `keyword3`, `keyword4`, `keyword5` only to `php` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the keywords are ALLWAYS after `<a href="//examples.com/position/`, this is doing the job:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<a href="/position/memory1"> kw random</a>
<a href="/position/memory2"> kw2 random2</a>
<a href="/position/memory3"> 123 orange</a>
<a href="/position/memory4"> test apple</a>
<a href="/position/memory5"> bla</a>
<div>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword1"> kw random</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword2"> kw2 random2</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword3" rel="nofollow"> 123 orange</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword4"> test apple</a>
    <a href="//examples.com/position/keyword5" title="something"> bla</a>
</div>
EOD;

preg_match_all('~<a href="//examples.com/position/([^"]+)~', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "keyword1"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "keyword2"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "keyword3"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "keyword4"
  [4]=>
  string(8) "keyword5"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using preg_match function :

```
// $lines is your string
// I think the regex is ok
preg_match_all("/(?<=\/position\/).+(?=\\")/", $lines, $output_array);

var_dump($output_array);
```

Comment: i've added:
preg_match_all("/(?<=\/\/examples.com\/position\/).+(?=[^\"])/", $lines, $output_array);

but it wont split to another array element after first double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Capture the href value and the text of the anchor. Then evaluate for a match on the link. Should be self explanatory.

```
<?php
 $data = '
<a href="/position/memory1"> Bkw random</a>
<a href="/position/memory2">B kw2 random2</a>
<a href="/position/memory3"> 123 orange</a>
<a href="/position/memory4"> test apple</a>
<a href="/position/memory5"> bla</a>
<a href="//examples.com/position/keyword1"> Akw random</a>
<a href="//examples.com/position/keyword2"> Akw2 random2</a>
<a href="//examples.com/position/keyword3" rel="nofollow"> 123 orange</a>
<a href="//examples.com/position/keyword4"> test apple</a>
<a href="//examples.com/position/keyword5" title="something"> bla</a>
';


$matches = [];
$needles = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword4', 'keyword5'];

preg_match_all('#<a\s+href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)</a>#i', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {            
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if (stristr($match[1], $needle) !== false) {
            echo $match[2];
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure I follow your comments.  Parts are there I think for what you need...

```
//           $match[1]              $match[2]
//<a href=" |/position/memory1| "> |Bkw random| </a>
```

Comment: idea is ok, but my keywordX is dynamic, so i'm just colecting some keywords

Comment: Does that mean you want to collect everything between each open and close `<a>` tag instance? Suppose confused then by what you mean when saying "how to extact keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4,keyword5 only to php array?"

Comment: sorry abotu that, they keywordX stuff is dynamic, and also i wont collect another part of the href=/position/, only with href=domain/position/XXXXX till double quotes

Comment: i wont extract /position/memory1
only <a href="//examples.com/position/******"
part with stars till double quotes